# Why is my MVC actionlink taking me to the URL with a Length querystring value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

There isn't really much I can do in the way of explanation on this one.

Simply put, I'm trying to render this link:

```
<a class="button active-button" href="/Home/Register">Register</a>
```

My ActionLink looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "button active-button" })
```

Which renders this link:

```
<a class="button active-button" href="/Home/Register?Length=4">Register</a>
```

I don't understand where the QueryString value is coming from so where have I made my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are calling the wrong overload of `ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home", null, new { @class = "button active-button" })
```

Comment: I thought it was but didn't know what else to do... Note to self: learn razor properly :/ Anyway thanks :) added the null and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is due to wrong overload as mentioned in another answer.If you are confused about which overload should be used then you can use visual studio intellisence.

In `MVC3+` you have this

```
Html.ActionLink("Register", 
                "Register",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "Home",  // <-- Controller Name.
                 null, // <-- Route arguments..you don't need this
                new {@class = "button active-button"}// <-- htmlArguments
                )
```